# KineticJs Handwriting Selecting Path/Strokes

Tags: kineticjs

Is there any way to select handwriting (group of paths/strokes) on KineticJs? Writing on canvas and then sending to server for recognition is rather trivial however I'm wondering if possible to select a handwritten word. Unless I"m missing something this may not be possible as it would be in SVG. Any information would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've since gotten pretty deep into to handwriting recognition etc. I can confirm the answer regarding outputting the stage is not correct. Although it will output the stage that is not the question. For completeness the question was related to selecting strokes/points as a single object, much like you would in SVG.

Handwriting on a canvas is made up of strokes/points. The are not a referenced objects on the canvas. You can use a library such as [fabricjs](http://fabricjs.com/) which I've found to be quite useful in this regard of taking a group of strokes. Also the developer of fabric is very attentive to the project.

Answer (score 1):

Very possible. You can write on the stage by creating lines and pushing points to them. then you can do:

```
 stage.toImage();
 //or
 stage.toDataURL();
```

and send it to your server for recognition.